# Formula in NHibernate Criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to add formula to a Projection in NHibernate Criteria:

I have something like this:

```
Emp Id    Name   Level   Points  
1         Mike   1       50  
2         Jeff   2       100  
3         Steve  3       320
```

I would like the results to be ( Level * Points ):

```
Emp Id    Name   Result  
1         Mike   50     (1*50)
2         Jeff   200    (2*100)
3         Steve  960    (3*320)
```

This is part of my DetachedCriteria that is why I need this in criteria NOT at entity level. Any other way is welcome as long as it is done using Projections.XXXX(..)

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate doesn't have this functionality out of the box. Here is the implementation of [OperatorProjection](http://savale.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html)

If DetachedCriteria API is not so crucial you can translate your DetachedCriteria into Detached QueryOver:

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<Entity>().Select(x => x.Level * x.Points);
```

Comment: I'm getting this "Could not determine member from (x.Level * x.Points)". Any idea ?

Comment: I think it is not possible. See this: [http://osdir.com/ml/nhusers/2010-12/msg00375.html](http://osdir.com/ml/nhusers/2010-12/msg00375.html)